# Is it possible to return all computers in AD in python

Tags: python, windows, active-directory

How could I search AD for all computer names?

Comment: You might also try posting your question at http://serverfault.com/ which is for sa's and desktop support folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that tou can find in [Active Directory Cookbook Python stuff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/ad_cookbook.html) what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It's not great code -- if you're familiar enough with the Windows API I'd recommend using the `win32con` to do so. However, this is quite functional:

```
import subprocess

splitstring = "\\r\\n"
bCompList = subprocess.check_output(['dsquery', 'computer', 'domainroot',
                                     '-scope', 'subtree', '-limit', '0'])
compList = str(bCompList)[2:-5].split(splitstring)
```

The `subprocess` module is used to run external commands; I suggest [reading up on the documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess). `subprocess.check_output` captures and returns the output of the command from stdout. (Note that the command is a list. That's important!)

In this case, we're using `dsquery computer` to query the entire domain (`'domainroot'`) for all computer objects (`'limit', '0'`). This returns a binary string -- stored here in `bCompList`.

Since it's a binary string, we'll probably want to convert it to a 'standard' string format to work with -- that's why we use `str()`. We can use slicing to trim off the 'junk' characters (the "`b`" which indicated the string was binary, and the trailing `'\\r\\n'` garbage.) That resultant string then gets used by `split()` to break it up into a list.

Incidentally, if you want to trim off the quotation marks `dsquery computer` places around each computer object, change the slicing to `[3:-6]` and change `splitstring = "\\r\\n"` to `splitstring = "\"\\r\\n\""`.

There are two significant caveats to this code, however:

- It must be run on a computer with the Windows "AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools" feature installed (at least, that's what they're called in Windows Server 2008 R2.)
- You need to be logged in as an AD user with appropriate privileges. (Alternatively, you could include `'-u', username, '-p', password` in the command argument list, replacing `username` and `password` with the appropriate credentials.)